# Custom Filtering using Microsoft Dynamics 365

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

And for my very first Stack overflow question I have an issue where I need to create a dashboard where the only thing that is shown on the dashboard is where a 'case' has been moved from one queue to another. In my instance, this is doing using an 'event' called Assign.

But when looking for this event in my standard list of filtering options 'event' is not there.

I'll give you some background. We receive emails and these go through some automatic record creation rules but sometimes we get this wrong. I need to know how many of these cases are then passed to a different queue.

I'd prefer not to have to create another process to be able to do this for me so any help would be appreciated.

I've tried creating a filter using the standard filter options but these do not give me what I need

Comment: How would you determine if a given incident row is meant to show up in this view, if you had to do it manually right now ?

Comment: Currently I have to go into each case and view the audit history table which is a pain and not really giving me the insight I need (receiving 10k cases per day)

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, accessing the audit history isn't possible from a Dashboard.

My guess is that the best approach available is to have a custom field (e.g. `new_HasBeenReassigned`) and then write a plugin that sets this field when a CASE record is reassigned.

You could also use a Cloud Flow, although my personal preference is a plugin for this scenario because it can be synchronous, and can prevent the save if the error occurs.